# Hibernate @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) ignored

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a lazy `@ManyToOne` column on Purchase defined as:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
Sale sale = null
```

However, when I load the entity from db, it gets directly loaded:

```
Purchase purchase = em.find(Purchase.class, id);
PersistenceUnitUtil unitUtil = em
        .getEntityManagerFactory()
        .getPersistenceUnitUtil();
System.err.println(unitUtil.isLoaded(purchase, "sale"));
```

This will return `true` even though the field should not yet be loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

(Hibernate 4.3.11.Final)

Answer (score 2):

Because it is nullable field. Hibernate cannot know if the value exists in the db or not, so it must query db to assign null or a value to the field.

Comment: So what could I do to prevent this?

Comment: Not so many options as I know. One way is "buildtime bytecode instrumentation". http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

Comment: So why this function is even there when it cannot never work? I even tried `nullable = false` with no effect.

Comment: @Vojtěch The function works in some cicrumstances, e.g. when you are using the instrumentation. But it is not guaranteed, just "best effort".